# WordPress shortcode with multiline parameters

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

How to insert shortcode with more parameters and multiline into WordPress page?
Backslash used to work as a line separator:

```
[my_shorcode parameter_1=10 \
   parameter_2=20 \
   parameter_3="test"]
```

But it doesn't work in the latest WordPress version. I want to use more lines for better readability of the code.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for *@Arvind K.* for advice

> This is not good idea since it breaks normal post editing behavior.
>   Rather you should try to keep shortcodes "short

**I've been solving this problem by the way**

**1.** I have used shortcode this way `[my-shortcode id="1"]`

**2.** I have created post type **My Shortcodes**

**3.** The `id` for step **1.** is the **My Shortcodes** post **id**

**4.** In **ACF (Custom fields)** I have created fields for **My Shortcodes**

*(Field - is shortcode param)*

**5.** Then you could use your **My Shortcodes** post for getting fields.

```
add_shortcode( 'my-shortcode', function ( $atts, $content ) {    
    $custom_shortcode_id = $atts['id'];

    $parameter_1 = get_field( 'parameter_1', $custom_shortcode_id );
    $parameter_2 = get_field( 'parameter_2', $custom_shortcode_id );

    return "Your shortcode content $parameter_1, $parameter_2";
} );
```

Comment: That's great idea to put parameters inside attribute. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I removed 2 WordPress filters and it works fine now.

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );                                                                                                                              
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

Comment: This is not good idea since it breaks normal post editing behavior. Rather you should try to keep shortcodes "short"